# How to redirect a page in java without servlets

Tags: java

I want to redirect a page without using java servlets, is it possible? if possible please tell me how to redirect works and send me the code snippet

thanks in advance.
Jampanna

Comment: Did you try to google it? What you found?

Comment: how are you planning to receive a http request in your solution? then some one might be able to help you!

Comment: do you want to redirect from javascript or you want to send some data to server and then redirect..?

Comment: Describe your question properly; provide sufficient information while asking question.

Comment: Actually my requirement is if session time out is up then without sending any request to the server I need to redirect a new page. when session time is up am getting the notification from MyListener class which is implementing HttpSessionListener's sessionDestroyed method. bt in that method doesn't contains request and response objects to use response.sendRedirect("some.do"). that's the reason without using request and response objects I have to redirect the page

Comment: why don't use a meta tag...

Comment: I successfully completed my task using meta tags but I don't want to refresh the page.

Comment: You mean you want to redirect your page from client without the help of server, but the redirect trigger should be initiated by server?

Comment: server automatically calling the HttpSession Listener when the session time completed without any client interaction,(ie server calling sessionDestroyed(...) method of HttpSessionListener) so my idea is, by using this method I redirect the page. but in this method no request and response objects are available.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you're not using any better web framework you could use:

From JSTL tag librarie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). I've had decent luck with [HTTP Rewrite Filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use Struts2 with action,  the following is an example, you can try it!


<action name="login" class="LoginAction">
   <result name="success" type="velocity">/pages/logok.vm</result>
   <result name="redirect_1" type="redirect">showInfo.do</result>
   <result name="redirect_2" type="redirect">showInfo.do?name=yangzi</result>
   <result name="redirect_3" type="redirect">showInfo.do?name=${name}</result>
   <result name="redirect_4" type= "redirect">
              <param name="actionName">showInfo</param>
              <param name="name">${name}</param>
    </result>  

</action>
```

Comment: I'm using struts1.1 version. Is it possible in struts1.1?

Comment: sorry, i don't know whether it is.